# Number of different occurrences in an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, count

Im having some trouble getting the total of different occurences in an array of strings , lets say I have a struct like this, which is already filled up with brands for each member. struct[1].brand="Fiat" , etc..

```
typedef struct{
  char brand[25];
}CarStruct

CarStruct struct[100];

void countDifferentBrands(){
    char *cPtr;
    cPtr=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int i,j, count=0;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            for(j=0 ; j<100 ; j++){
                    if( strcmp( struct[i].brand ,(cPtr+j) ) == 0  ){                            
                            j=100;
                    }
                    else{
                            strcpy((cPtr+count), struct[i].brand);
                            count++;
                    }
            }
    }
    printf("Different brands:%d\n",count);
}
```

I cant seem to get the logic right to do this, I'd like a bit of help if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `cPtr` -- you can compare different `CarStruct` items against each other, directly.

For each item in the list, start off assuming it's unique. Check it against every previous item in the list; if a match is found, note that it's *not* unique and break out. If you exit the loop with `unique` still true, increment your count.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
  int unique = 1;

  for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
    if ( strcmp( struct[i].brand, struct[j].brand ) == 0  ) {
      unique = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (unique)
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very nice, clean and simple .